# Creating interactive 3d cubes

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d

I am trying to create a structure made up of 3D cubes stacked on top of each other. Each of the elements (The cubes) in the structure are interactive. On mouse-hover event the individual cube has the 'bounce' effect, letting the user know that cube is interactive. On mouse-click  event a modal popup shows information about individual cubes.

I have been able to create the 2D version of this, however wondering what is the best way to create the 3D version. Currently using a canvas element to draw a square (2d version of the cube). I was trying to add box shadows to each canvas element, but realizing I might only be able to do that to div elements and not canvas elements.

Is this possible?

```
#canvas .box-shadow-3d{
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px Black,
            2px 2px 0px Black,
            3px 3px 0px Black,
            4px 4px 0px Black,
            5px 5px 0px Black,
            6px 6px 0px Black;
```

}

Or do I need to do all the math to create these cubes ? Or would it be better to use div elements and box-shadows?

Here is what I am thinking:-

https://jsfiddle.net/teg0h13k/6/

Comment: You might find these articles interesting: [Intro to CSS 3D transforms](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/cube) and [Create a CSS Cube](https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube).

Answer (score -2):

Something I'd recommend learning is three.js. It's a powerful library used specifically for drawing cubes and 3d objects on javascript and html. An example I created is shown here.

https://cloudynet.tk/projects/three/code.html